# sed/awk remove newline on two pattern matches

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a .pem file that after some formatting it shows like this:

```
-----BEGIN
RSA
PRIVATE
KEY-----
MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAoK3D4mMIRnzPaYqHidgpBnDDzLlcYYd0GoB0pQGyGSHDW7KO3K+VeJP90GhE
ZTEWJLp2N5DR/KT+5Vg7cgdx/GCCrnlbW0McP/IvkYAuWCgbzoXH9eE+kDRtAmurBYCk7OTOwQ26
..........................LONG LONG LONG KEY................................
QRRLFsXua9spUh0yPd163IZStKZMhZBPJfMaqbi1WF+j21DdYyS0qpaZQRjFzRLvGuXeGLZG/COD
ip10XRJMMXY0m14bqOTcqKTya/5PTJIjDWC22+soIjLy0ZjWKo9n05Oal2t4q35kbos=
-----END
RSA
PRIVATE
KEY-----
```

And I obviously need to be like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAoK3D4mMIRnzPaYqHidgpBnDDzLlcYYd0GoB0pQGyGSHDW7KO3K+VeJP90GhE
ZTEWJLp2N5DR/KT+5Vg7cgdx/GCCrnlbW0McP/IvkYAuWCgbzoXH9eE+kDRtAmurBYCk7OTOwQ26
..........................LONG LONG LONG KEY................................
QRRLFsXua9spUh0yPd163IZStKZMhZBPJfMaqbi1WF+j21DdYyS0qpaZQRjFzRLvGuXeGLZG/COD
ip10XRJMMXY0m14bqOTcqKTya/5PTJIjDWC22+soIjLy0ZjWKo9n05Oal2t4q35kbos=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

How can I do it using `awk` or `sed`?

All the tutorials that I've found online shows how to do it for the whole text or for one type of pattern like `aaaabbbaaacccc` which I found confusing.

I tried something like this:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < test.pem  | awk '/BEGIN\nRSA\nPRIVATE\n$/ { printf("%s\t", $0); next } 1' > test-format.pem
```

But that failed.

I don't know if it matters or not, but I'm doing this in a shell `#!/bin/sh` script in a `python:3.5-alpine` docker container.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way with `sed`:

```
sed -e '/^---/ {
  :1
  $!N
  s/\n/ /
  /---$/!b1
}' <file
```

This approach does the job straight way:

- If line start with `---`, then enter the code block
- Inside code block, we create a loop label named `1`
- We read `N`ext line of the input if current line is not the last line `$`
- Replace newline `\n` with a space
- If next line does end with `---`, break `!` the loop, otherwise restart the loop `b1`

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's going on in this sed please?

Comment: Gived +1 for you.

Comment: If I could +1 you I would.. This is the fastest and straight to the point solution.. Thank you!

Comment: @Fadi It looks like you're at 15 rep, so you should be able to now.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the key lines should be collected in one long line too:

```
sed '
    :a
    N
    /\n-\|-\n/{
        P
        D
    }
    s/\n/ /
    ta
    ' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another `sed`:

```
sed '/^---/,/---$/{H;/^---/h;/---$/!d;x;s/\n/ /g;}' infile
```

this one uses a range and the hold buffer. It appends each line in that range to the hold buffer, overwriting it if it's the start of range; it deletes the line if it's not the end of range else it exchanges buffers and replaces all newlines with spaces.
And a different approach with `ed`:

```
ed -s infile <<\IN
?^---?,.-s/$/ /
?^---?,$j
1,/---$/-s/$/ /
1,/---$/j
w
q
IN
```

This one uses four ranges: first it searches backwards (`ed` starts at end of file) and it appends a space to end of each line in the first range and then joins the lines in the second range (which are actually lines in the first one plus one more line); it then does the same but starting from the beginning of the file.

Comment: The `ed` solution will edit the file in-place, replace `w` with `,p` if you just want to print the result.

Answer (score 2):

Doing the posix version as requested in the comment:

```
#!/bin/sh
jump=1

while IFS= read -r lin; do

  case $lin in 
    ----*)
        jump=0
    ;;
    *----)
        jump=1
    ;;
  esac

  if [ "$jump" = "1" ]; then 
        printf '%s\n' "$lin" 
  else
        printf '%s' "$lin "
  fi

done <"$1"
```

To call it:

```
./script file.txt >thedest.txt
```

Comment: You may not want to use shell loop for processing text http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/38906

Comment: Ok and if you do not have cut, sed, awk but just echo and while, how do you solve this problem?

Comment: Then you must use the shell, of course, but use it the right way. Also, `cut`, `sed`, `awk` or any other standard tools can be seen in most *nix, unlike `bash`, which is only often seen in GNU/Linux.

Comment: Will this work for `#!/bin/sh` ? Also, the reason why I was asking for sed/awk is because I'm creating a new pem file and echoing the contents then I'm formatting it. Not sure how it will work with this method.

Comment: I tested in my debian with ksh and dash and it works. I think it can run, but maybe you will need to replace the condition jump = 1 to a traditional if.

Comment: Your one is fine, it will run in any POSIX shell. But you need `while IFS= read -r`, see the link I posted above

Comment: Thank you. You can add this to the post, i will allow you.

Comment: This isn't working for me btw..

Comment: Ok i am doing a POSIX version...

Comment: It is Better now?

Comment: Yes.. Thank you so much for the script, this will be useful for later use! :) Once I have enough points I'll come back and +1 you.. haha